# Find the record with the lest amount of associated records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I just asked this question [Find the oldest record in a join between two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623793/find-the-oldest-record-in-a-join-between-two-tables/11623914#11623914) and got a great answer to my question. The problem is that is is not quite what I was looking for (my fault)

Consider the following MySQL tables

```
Table: Questions
   ID

Table: Results
   ID 
   Created - When this record was added. 
   Q_ID - A FK to the Question table
```

Example data

```
Table: Questions
   ID 
   ----
    1
    8
   15
   55

Table: Results
   ID | Created | Q_ID 
   --------------------
    1 |   12:02 |    1 
    2 |   12:03 |   15 
    3 |   12:04 |    8
```

Using the following query, it will return all the records that do not have results associated with them, if all records have results then it will return the question with the oldest result.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    questions
    LEFT JOIN results
        ON results.q_id = questions.id
ORDER BY
    ISNULL(results.id) DESC, results.created ASC
LIMIT 1
```

What I am actually looking for is for any question that has not been answered, then to sort the question my the count of how many times they have been answered. The lest answered questions should be at the top.

Comment: Seems a bit confusing. Given your example, what question would you expect to be at the top of the resulting set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you each question, and the number of results associated it (even if no results exist).  They will be ordered with the lowest count at the top:

```
SELECT Questions.ID, COUNT(Results.ID) Result_Count
FROM
    Questions
    LEFT JOIN Results ON Questions.ID = Results.Q_ID
GROUP BY Questions.ID
ORDER BY COUNT(Results.ID)
```

Is this what you had in mind?